# How to make div scroll down with a page once it reaches top of page?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I know title is a bit confusing ;D but basically what I want to do is clearly demonstrated on this website http://9gag.com scroll down and pay attention to sidebar, there are 2 advertisements once 2nd advertisement reaches top of the page it starts scrolling down with a page.

I would like to know how to do this? html/css or jQuery solutions are prefared.

Comment: The easiest way is to listen to the body tag's scroll event, then when the scrollTop gets past a certain amount, add a class to the advertisement making it's position fixed, then removing the class when the scrollTop gets back to lower than that amount. I don't have code to post as a sample so i won't post it as an answer.

Comment: @KevinB thnx, but I'm not good with the code, so I'd prefare a code, but thnx for a logic!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Kevin points out, what you need to do is to listen to the document's `scroll` event. When that is fired, you'll want to look at the value of `scrollTop`.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

    var useFixedSidebar = $(document).scrollTop() >= myThresholdValue;
    $('.my-sidebar-items').toggleClass('fixed', useFixedSidebar);

});
```

And your CSS would basically look like this:

```
.my-sidebar-items.fixedSidebar { position: fixed; }
```

A complicating factor is that you'll probably want the items to be fixed in their new, top positions, and you would want to do something like this:

```
.my-sidebar-items.fixedSidebar { position: fixed; top: 0 }
```

However, that would probably stack your items on top of one another. A solution to that would be to put the `fixedSidebar` class on a container, and use the class as described.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jPxEY/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use sticky bars http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/sticky or jQuery Waypoints http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/